# how to solve input tensor error in adopting pre-trained keras models

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to adopt a pre-trained keras model as follow, but it requires an input to be a tensor. can anyone help to solve it?

```
from keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19
inputs = layers.Input(shape = (32,32,4))

vgg_model = VGG19(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
vgg_model.trainable = False

x = tensorflow.keras.layers.Flatten(name='flatten')(vgg_model)
x = tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', name='fc1')(x)
x = tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', name='fc2')(x)
x = tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(1,name='predictions')(x)
new_model = tensorflow.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
new_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', 
                   metrics=['mae'])
```

error:

```
TypeError: Inputs to a layer should be tensors. Got: <keras.engine.functional.Functional object at 0x000001F48267B588>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the `VGG19` as your base model, you will have to use its output as the input to your custom model:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19


vgg_model = VGG19(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(32, 32, 3))
vgg_model.trainable = False

x = vgg_model.output
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', name='fc1')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', name='fc2')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, name='predictions')(x)
new_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=vgg_model.input, outputs=x)
new_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', 
                   metrics=['mae'])

new_model(tf.random.normal((1, 32, 32, 3)))
```

Note that I removed your `Flatten layer`, since the output from the `vgg_model` already has the shape `(batch_size, features)`.

Comment: I need to change the input size to (32,32,4). Isn't it possible?, is there any way to change the input dimension?

Comment: Updated answer. You can have a custom shape but you have to have 3 channels (the last dimension), you cannot have 4. That is simply a limitation of the `VGG19` model.

Comment: is it possible to give the input as: `inputs = layers.Input(shape = (32,32,3))`

Comment: Yes,  I already updated that option. Check the `VGG19(*)` part.

Comment: would you please let me know which architecture has the capability to read more than 3 channels?

Comment: Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62989495/tensorflow-builtin-model-architectures-for-more-than-3-rgb-channels)